# Count # of valus that exist in column string

Tags: mysql

I am trying to count # of rows where a value exists in any string of another table. Here is my example data:

| ToolCode |
| --- |
| Drill |
| Screwdriver |
| Saw |

| WorkCenter |
| --- |
| Screwdriver1 |
| Drill1 |
| Saw2 |
| Saw3 |
| Screwdriver15 |
| Drill 12 |
| Saw10 |

So the totals would be:

| Tool Code | Quantity |
| --- | --- |
| Drill | 2 |
| Saw | 3 |
| Screwdriver | 2 |

I attempted to use different count by len functions, but was unable to make it work. I am hoping for help in this matter and getting an example of what to do.

```
Select ToolCode, Len(ToolCode), Count(WorkCenter)
FROM JT_ToolCode, JT_WorkCenter
WHERE ToolCode = Left(Workcenter,Len(ToolCode))
Group By ToolCode, WorkCenter
```

Comment: Why would you use `WorkCenter` as part of your GROUP BY here? That makes absolutely no sense - you _want_ the records that contain `Screwdriver1` and `Screwdriver15` to be grouped together, but grouping by those _different_ values would of course mean they get put into separate groups.

Comment: If you have any control over the schema then it seems like adding a foreign key from WorkCenter to ToolCode would make things much easier overall.

Comment: So the WorkCenter always **starts** with the same string as ToolCode? Or should e.g. `1Screwdriver1` also be grouped to `Screwdriver`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try something like this:

```
SELECT ToolCode.ToolCode, COUNT(*) AS Quantity
FROM ToolCode
JOIN WorkCenter ON WorkCenter.WorkCenter LIKE CONCAT('%', ToolCode.ToolCode, '%')
GROUP BY ToolCode.ToolCode;
```

This query looks at both the ToolCode and WorkCenter tables. It checks if each tool is mentioned in any work center. Then, it counts how many times each tool appears in the work centers and groups the results by tool.

Comment: This worked perfectly!! Thank you. I don't know why I never thought of using the wildcard and was trying to use left / len.

Answer (score 0):

While not efficient this would work by simply joining on a like.

[Demos](https://dbfiddle.uk/zytmvp_f)

Note: this assumes any occurrence of a toolcode in a workcenter is desired a like to the toolcode.  however you could get false or double counts if you have tool codes like Drill and PneumaticDrill, as Drill will include PneumaticDrill in it's count. as in this [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/YwSssa7l)

```
SELECT ToolCode, count(WorkCenter) WorkCenterCount 
FROM CTE1 --Change to your Name
LEFT JOIN CTE2 --Change to your tableName
 on CTE2.WorkCenter like concat('%', CTE1.ToolCode,'%')
GROUP BY  toolcode
```

Or using an inline view which runs for each row in the first table getting a count from the second

```
SELECT ToolCode, (SELECT Count(*) 
                  FROM CTE2 
                  WHERE CTE2.WorkCenter Like concat('%',CTE1.TOOLCODE,'%')) as WorkCenterCount 
FROM CTE1
ORDER BY ToolCOde
```

Giving us:

```
+-------------+-------------------+
|  ToolCode   | WorkCenterCount |
+-------------+-------------------+
| Drill       |                 2 |
| Saw         |                 3 |
| Screwdriver |                 2 |
+-------------+-------------------+
```